# onChange select not working

Tags: javascript, onchange

I have a drop down select with a load of colors as the options
I need to change the color of a div (called someDiv) in this case when an option is chosen

the options look like this

```
<select id="evt_color">
<option value="#1B1404" style="background:#1B1404;">Acadia</option>
</select
```

and so on

```
<script type="text/javascript;">
$("#evt_color").change(function() {
$("#someDiv").css("background-color", $(this).val());
});
</script>
```

I have managed to get this working on Firefox only, can anyone help me with another solution
or work around please

Paul

Comment: Your code is already working in Chrome - http://jsfiddle.net/L9MPH/1/

Comment: Can you reply showing the actual problem? Did you not check my jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

trigger("change"); the last change makes no since :)

Comment: sorry yes it is the same with that removed, my typo

Comment: do you have tried "backgroundColor" or simply "background" ? i had this problem some time ago

Comment: just tried that thnx, and background and bgcolor, none work :(

Comment: bgcolor is only an old html attribute. the best css name which work in jquery are the style attributes: (the table is german, sorry. but i dont find the englisch version right now: http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/style.htm#style_eigenschaften)

Comment: Just checked your fiddle Zenith yes and it seem ok but I am uploading what I have and will give a link, I wonder if it is something to do with the divs and possition attyributes?

Comment: You would not believe what it was.....and it now works in IE too I simply change the <sript type="text/javascript> to <script>

Answer (score 0):

You would not believe what it was and it now works in IE too. I simply change the `<sript type="text/javascript>` to `<script>`.